# How to find linear transformation to satisfy a non-standard dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the non-standard dot product $\langle x,y\rangle^* = x^TA y$ where

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -2 & 2 \\
-2 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Find a matrix representation of arbitrary linear mapping $f :\Bbb R^3 → \Bbb R^3$ satisfying the condition $$∀x, y ∈\Bbb R^3\quad \langle f(x),f(y)\rangle=\langle x,y \rangle ^*$$ where $\langle ·,·\rangle$ is a standard dot product.

I tried something with bilinear forms but failed. Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: @AnneBauval, edited question, thank you. Star is just a notation to differentiate between the standard dot product and the given one.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I overlooked your 1st line. As for your problem: $(Mx)^T(My)=x^TAy$ for all $x,y$ iff $M^TM=A.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is represented by a matrix $B$ then the condition can be rewritten as

$$\langle Bx,Bx \rangle = (Bx)^TBy = x^TAy \iff x^TB^TBy = x^TAy$$
for all $x$ and $y$.

In particular for the the canonical basis vectors $e_i$, $e_j$ then you have
$$ e_i^TB^TBe_j = e_i^TAe_j.$$
This last equality is simply $$ (B^TB)_{ij} = A_{ij}.$$
That is $$ B^TB = A.$$

Therefore we must find such a matrix $B.$ One method is to diagonalise $A$ and write it as
$$A =  Q^T\Lambda Q$$
if all the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive then you can define the matrix $\Lambda^{1/2}$ obtained from $\Lambda$ by taking the square root on the whole diagonal. This yields

$$ A = Q^T\Lambda Q = Q^T (\Lambda^{1/2})^T\Lambda^{1/2}Q = (\Lambda^{1/2} Q)^T (\Lambda^{1/2}Q)$$

If one eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is negative then writing $A = B^TB$ is not possible since if you take a corresponding eigenvector $x$ then you would have both

$$ x^TAx = x^T\lambda x = \lambda \Vert x \Vert^2  < 0 $$
and $$ x^TAx = x^TB^TBx  = (Bx)^T(Bx)= \Vert Bx \Vert^2.$$